# typehint for tuple constructor

Tags: python, mypy

The following code gives error for tuple constructor:

```
def foo() -> tuple[int, int, bool]:
 a: int = 1
 b: int = 2
 c: bool = True
 
 results: tuple[int, int, bool] = tuple((a, b, c))   # mypy fails
 results: tuple[int, int, bool] = (a, b, c) # mypy success
 results: tuple[int, int, bool] = a, b, c   # mypy success
 
 return results
```

Error as below:
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[object, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int, bool]")  [assignment]

edited:
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int, bool]")

Comment: So, you really must provide a [mcve], this fails complainging that `c` doesn't exist. When I fix that and change `c` to `f`, and remove the subsequent re-assignments of `results`, I get an error `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int, bool]")  [assignment]`

Comment: I guess this is because the `tuple` constructor expects an **iterable** as an argument, and essentialy the constructor is something like `def tuple(data: Iterable[T]) -> tuple[T, ...]`, So everything is being promoted to the safest super type, which is `int` (since you are getting `object`, I suspect your other type is like `str` or something else that forces it to use `object` as the safest type that is a base type of every other tpye in the `tuple`)

Comment: ^^^ seems likely. oddly i couldn't find the constructor in typeshed

Comment: Hi juanpa, sorry. error during copy-paste. I have edited the code.

Comment: what version of `mypy` are you getting, because I'm still not getting the error about the unexpected type `Tuple[object, ...]`, I get `Tuple[int, ...]`

Comment: I am using mypy = "^0.991"

Answer (score 0):

Note, I get a slightly different error:

```
x.py:6: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int, bool]")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

With:

```
mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ mypy --version
mypy 0.990 (compiled: yes)
```

So, you can think of tuple being type-hinted like this (see that actual [`typeshed` hints here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/578cebe1c519dcad769c39bf60123265f26368d7/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L911):

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")

class tuple(object):
    def __new__(cls, data: typing.Iterable[T]) -> tuple[T, ...]:
        ...
```

So the type of the literal:

```py
data: tuple[int, int, bool] = (a, b, c)
```

gets promoted to:

```py
data: tuple[int, ...]
```

Note, that `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

I suspect this is what is happening with your real example, (maybe you aren't using `bool` but something like `str`, in which case it has to promote to `object`).

Comment: yes, I was trying different combinations of variables. yes with str it gives object.

Comment: @winter please always try to make sure that the error message you are reporting is the one you produce with the actual code you post in the question

Comment: why do you refer to `__new__`? I would have thought `__init__`, or perhaps even `__call__` on a metaclass would be relevant, but why `__new__`?

Comment: i notice you also changed `cls: type[Self]` to `self` too

Comment: @joel because `__new__` is the constructor for `tuple` objects, `tuple` does not have an `__init__` (other than the `__init__` inherited from `object` which takes no arguments and does nothing). And `__call__` on the metaclass needs to be too permissive, indeed, it is in the link I provided ([see here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/578cebe1c519dcad769c39bf60123265f26368d7/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L172).

Comment: @joel that really doesn't change anything about the situation. Note, `self` is equivalent to `cls`, the name or the argument is irrelevant, I omitted the annotation because it isn't relevant for what's going on here. Note, I didn't transcribe the definition, I wrote out the above and then found the actual typeshed definition, but they are equivalent for the purposes of this question.